# What is the fermion mass matrix for a Yukawa Lagrangian?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, fermions

For a 2-scalars theory like
$$\mathcal{L}_{\phi\varphi}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial\phi)^2-\frac{m_\phi^2}{2}\phi^2+\frac{1}{2}(\partial\varphi)^2-\frac{m_\varphi^2}{2}\varphi^2+\frac{\lambda}{2}\phi^2\varphi^2$$
the mass matrix for the one of the scalars is fairly easy to compute:
$$M^2=\frac{\delta^2\mathcal{L}}{\delta\phi\delta\phi}\Bigg|_{k=0}=\lambda\varphi^2-m_\phi^2$$
But what about a Yukawa theory (or any fermionic theory, really)? If the Lagrangian is
$$\mathcal{L}_{\psi\varphi}=\bar\psi(i\hat\partial-m_\psi)\psi+\frac{1}{2}(\partial\varphi)^2-\frac{m_\varphi^2}{2}\varphi^2-iy\bar\psi\psi\varphi$$
what do I derive my Lagrangian with respect to? I thought $\psi$ and $\bar\psi$, but the mass matrix should be of mass dimension $2$ and I only get a mass dimension $1$:
$$M^2\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{\delta^2\mathcal{L}}{\delta\bar\psi\delta\psi}\Bigg|_{k=0}=-iy\varphi-m_\psi$$
which is clearly wrong.

Comment: Your expression for the fermion mass matrix is obviously wrong. Fermions are of dimension 3/2 , so the double derivative is of dimension 1, so it should specify *M*. Your signs are flakey.